# How to get input from a function written in MATLAB to a Mex-file?

Tags: matlab, mex

I’m really new to MEX and MATLAB-language. How can i get input from a function written in MATLAB to a Mex-file, and after that, how can I give the mex file's output to a function in MATLAB?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This link is also especially helpful: http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/03/getting-started-with-mex-a-short-tutorial/

Comment: The duplicate link is directly above your text of the question.  The second link I recommend is in my first comment.... don't know what else you want.